# What is the syntax for IF AND OR C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am trying to do IF (SOMETHING && NOT) OR (SOMETHING && NOT)... but it is not working, can you see what I have done wrong?

```
if (MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.FRONT &&
!(MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("RHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("CHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("MET")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("SHS")

||

(MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.BACK &&
!(MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("RHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("CHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("MET")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("SHS")))))
```

Ignore the references to an API there but I am sure it still makes sense.

Comment: Which part isn't working for you?

Comment: combine it? `if ((MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.FRONT || MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.BACK)...`

Comment: To simply the `Contains` bit, you could use an array and do `myArray.Any(MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains)`, where `myArray` is an array of `"RHS", "CHS"...`

Comment: Basically it doesn't return true, but the condition is true as I have set it up as such in the application?

Comment: Array sounds good, I will try that.

Comment: I dont understand why people are marking the questions down, there was a mistake and now there is an answer and I can see the mistake, so its a valid question?

Comment: generally, such questions are not very useful for future reference for people with similar problems, because if they have similar problem they will not find this question in its current form, it's too specific for SO format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your parentheses wrong. This one should work:

```
if ((MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.FRONT &&
     !(MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("RHS") || 
       MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("CHS") || 
       MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("MET") || 
       MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("SHS"))) ||
    (MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.BACK &&
     !(MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("RHS") || 
       MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("CHS") || 
       MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("MET") || 
       MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("SHS"))))
```

That said, it's very unreadable. Try combining some of those into variables, e.g.:

```
bool profileCheck = MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("RHS") || MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("CHS") || 
                    MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("MET") || MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("SHS");

if ((MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.FRONT && !profileCheck) ||
    (MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.BACK && !profileCheck))
```

In this form I can see that it can be simplified:

```
if (!profileCheck && (MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.FRONT || MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.BACK))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want the Rotation to be either Front or Back and you don't want RHS but accept CHS, MET, SHS?

```
if ((MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.FRONT || MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.BACK) &&
(
!MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("RHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("CHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("MET")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("SHS")
)
)
```

Or if it is Are you saying you want the Rotation to be either Front or Back and you don't want any of RHS, CHS, MET, SHS?

```
if ((MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.FRONT || MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.BACK) &&
 !(
MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("RHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("CHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("MET")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("SHS")
)
)
```

Comment: No, I am trying to say == FRONT OR BACK && NOT RHS, CHS, MET, SHS

Answer (score 0):

Your Not part seems incorrect. You need `NOT` with all `OR` conditions

```
if ((MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.FRONT || MyBeam.Position.Rotation == Position.RotationEnum.BACK) &&
!((MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("RHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("CHS")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("MET")
|| MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString.Contains("SHS"))
```